# Creating visual designs for android applications

Tags: java, android

I've been on and off with Android development but one thing that has confused me is how do you do custom looking interfaces? I'm not exactly sure as to what terms to look for or how it is done. I've not found any working examples either.

What terms should I look for to learn how this is done?

Comment: You mean custom GUI ? Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/

Take look at that website should get you started, with the basics